# Is there an efficiency difference between finding by id and finding by class with JavaScript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an efficiency difference between finding by id and finding by class with JavaScript/jquery?

Is one better than the other? If so is it because indexes of ID or Class are made in the DOM somewhere?

Does it end up not mattering much?

Comment: Having a debate with colleagues whether the speed trade off is worth retrofitting some existing implementation; I'm arguing we're unlikely to see any difference.

Comment: *"Is one better than the other?"* - ID's and classes are used for different things so they're not comparable. You use an ID for unique elements on the page, and classes for sets of elements that share similar presentation / behavior.

Comment: Why not devise a benchmark based off your use case and try both ways? For example, take a flat source file of a few of your pages and apply a unique id for a set of nodes you want to test. Then run jQuery on it and the original class-based implementation (using separate source files to avoid caching/memoization). I suspect that, while they might have a large relative difference, the absolute difference will be insignificant.

Comment: Also, and I just remembered this, the sizzle.js selector engine (that powers jQuery) parses from right to left. This would suggest that you might get greatly better performance by improving specificity on the right side of your query. It may be that `#myId > li` performs significantly worse than `.myLiClassName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding by ID is *always* faster, no matter where (`getElementById()`, `$('#id')`, or even in regular CSS).

Since ID's are unique per page, they're much faster to find.

In addition, when using `$('#id')`, jQuery will map that back to the built-in `getElementById()`, which is the *fastest* way to query the DOM.

Comment: You overstate the difference if this is to be understood as a universal policy. He does ask if it matters *much*, which is case-dependent. In many cases, the answer is "no."

Comment: @Richard Simões - AFAIK, the document size will be the greatest contributor to the efficiency difference.

Answer (score 2):

Well, logically speaking, an ID would be more efficient, as there is (should be) only one of it, so once it finds it, it will stop searching. However I am not familiar with the jQuery source, I don't know how it actually works, that's from a logic perspective.

Comment: jQuery looks at the selector and if it finds a "#xxx" by itself, it uses `getElementById()`.  If not, it uses the Sizzle selector engine which in turn will use `querySelectorAll()` if it's available and will use it's own JS-based selector engine if not.

Answer (score 1):

For most browsers, the difference in speed between searching by id and searching by class name depends on how many elements have a given class. At best, there will be only one such element, and the search speed ought to be the same. At worst, there are a bazillion elements with a given class. Typically, though, you shouldn't have to worry about the speed of searching through 10-20 elements containing the same class.

A critical caveat, though: MSIE <= 8 has no native `getElementsByClassName`, so jQuery has to fall back to a full DOM tree search unless, e.g., the element name of the wanted element is also provided. Even then. `$('div.myclass')` may not be much help if your document is large and  exceedingly `div`-happy. Benchmarking is really the only way to find out.

Comment: `depends on how many elements have a given class`. No. It simply depends on how big the DOM is.